# How can I add a new disk to my existing Ubuntu Server 20.04.3?

Tags: gparted, hdd

I'm wondering how I can go about adding a new disk to my server? I'm unsure how to do this.

I've tried installing 'gparted' with this command

```
$sudo apt install gparted
```

But when I try to run it, it just spits out this message:

```
$sudo gparted
Unit boot.mount does not exist, proceeding anyway.
Unit tmp.mount does not exist, proceeding anyway.
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
(gpartedbin:10026): Gtk-WARNING **: 18:57:19.069: cannot open display:
```

Is there something I am doing wrong? I'm guessing from that message it's trying to open some GUI based version, but I've seen on some other sites people are using CLI based versions of it.

Comment: Did you try "parted"? gparted is the GTK version. parted is the command line version. You can also use fdisk. Are you asking for help partioning a new disk? That part is not clear.

Comment: I just tried that, and it worked. That's great! And yes, sorry I should of explained that better. I'm running the OS on a 256GB SSD, and I've a spare 250GB hard disk I wanna throw into it for extra storage, possibly encrypted also.